# lighttpd-cpp how to compile?

Tags: c++, lighttpd

I was trying to create my own module for lighttpd, after some minutes i've discovered that this is all in c! and i need maps  and some other class i've made in c++. so i come across http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/CppModules and also http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/CppHelperClasses there is (for lighttpd-cpp) a mercurial project with some demo modules written here, but no explanation on how to copile and integrate these in the lighttpd environment.. these also in the /src/ directory didn't compile (obviously, all dependancies are missing..

```
src]# cpp mod_blank.cpp -o a
In file included from mod_blank.cpp:5:
mod_blank.hpp:5:35: error: lighttpd-cpp/plugin.hpp: No such file or directory
mod_blank.hpp:7:30: error: boost/mpl/list.hpp: No such file or directory
```

anyone have some idea? similar experience or other way to do a custome module using c++ ?

#### Update

Thanks to messa i have installed scons, tryed to compile and i got these errors

```
./include/lighttpd-cpp/datatype_helpers.hpp:86: error: invalid conversion from 'long unsigned int' to 'config_values_type_t'
./include/lighttpd-cpp/datatype_helpers.hpp: In instantiation of 'const config_values_type_t config_option_traits_base<short int, 2ul>::value_enum':
./include/lighttpd-cpp/datatype_helpers.hpp:347:   instantiated from 'handler_t config_option<OptionType, ConfigScopeType, OptionTraits>::set_defaults(const server&) [with OptionType = short int, long unsigned int ConfigScopeType = 2ul, OptionTraits = config_option_traits<short int>]'
src/mod_blank.cpp:6:   instantiated from here
./include/lighttpd-cpp/datatype_helpers.hpp:243: error: uninitialized const 'config_option_traits_base<short int, 2ul>::value_enum'
./include/lighttpd-cpp/datatype_helpers.hpp: In instantiation of 'const config_values_type_t config_option_traits_base<bool, 4ul>::value_enum':
./include/lighttpd-cpp/datatype_helpers.hpp:347:   instantiated from 'handler_t config_option<OptionType, ConfigScopeType, OptionTraits>::set_defaults(const server&) [with OptionType = bool, long unsigned int ConfigScopeType = 2ul, OptionTraits = config_option_traits<bool>]'
src/mod_blank.cpp:6:   instantiated from here
./include/lighttpd-cpp/datatype_helpers.hpp:243: error: uninitialized const 'config_option_traits_base<bool, 4ul>::value_enum'
./include/lighttpd-cpp/datatype_helpers.hpp: In instantiation of 'const config_values_type_t config_option_traits_base<int, 3ul>::value_enum':
./include/lighttpd-cpp/datatype_helpers.hpp:347:   instantiated from 'handler_t config_option<OptionType, ConfigScopeType, OptionTraits>::set_defaults(const server&) [with OptionType = int, long unsigned int ConfigScopeType = 2ul, OptionTraits = config_option_traits<int>]'
src/mod_blank.cpp:6:   instantiated from here
./include/lighttpd-cpp/datatype_helpers.hpp:243: error: uninitialized const 'config_option_traits_base<int, 3ul>::value_enum'
./include/lighttpd-cpp/datatype_helpers.hpp: In instantiation of 'const config_values_type_t config_option_traits_base<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, 1ul>::value_enum':
./include/lighttpd-cpp/datatype_helpers.hpp:347:   instantiated from 'handler_t config_option<OptionType, ConfigScopeType, OptionTraits>::set_defaults(const server&) [with OptionType = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, long unsigned int ConfigScopeType = 2ul, OptionTraits = config_option_traits<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]'
src/mod_blank.cpp:6:   instantiated from here
./include/lighttpd-cpp/datatype_helpers.hpp:243: error: uninitialized const 'config_option_traits_base<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, 1ul>::value_enum'
```

i'm running centos 5.5 64bit i have already a version of lighttpd compiled and installed here, also i didn't understood what's the role of lighttpd-cpp in building new lighttpd modules using cpp,  i have  to build everything from lighttpd-cpp and use this version instead of my lighttpd 1.4.28 downloaded from http://www.lighttpd.net/? if yes that's sad because i may loose updates and version stability using not so well tested lighttpd source, and instead, if i have to implement then new modules in old lighttpd, how to do that? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are compiling it wrong - paths to header files are missing. You should use a build system, which is **[SCons](http://www.scons.org/)** in case of lighttpd-cpp. Install scons and then continue with [README](http://code.google.com/p/lighttpd-cpp/source/browse/README) :)

Comment: i've just foudn scons while you wrote your message, installed , and finally i can try to compile :) but another problem occurred..